# ORA-12154 error setting User DSN

Tags: oracle11g, dsn

I am trying to set up a user DSN on Windows 2012 server. Oracle Client, both 32 and 64 bit are installed as well as ODBC. They are installed on C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1 and C:\Oracle\product\11.2.0\client_2 respectively. I used ODBC Data Source Administrator (32 bit) to set up the DSN and used information as it exists in tnsname.ora file. However, when I test the connection I keep getting:

```
"Unable to connect
SQLState=08004
[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-12154: could not resolve the connect identifier specified"
```

I searched and they all point to an issue with tnsnames.ora file but all the info I entered when creating DSN is correct, Network Services and IIS_USRS have access to the folder containing the file, I put the service name in quotes as some suggested but just can't shake off the error.

Any ideas on what else I can check?

Comment: Are the two Oracle Homes sharing a tnsnames.ora file?  Or does each have a separate file?  Or is one using a different TNS resolution mechanism?  My first guess is that the 32-bit Oracle Home doesn't have that particular TNS alias defined.

Comment: They each have their own tnsname.ora files and they are identical.